# What's the reason of GCC's -Wconversion difference between C and C++?

Tags: c++, c, gcc

GCC has an option, `-Wconversion`, which enables conversion warnings:

> Warn for implicit conversions that may alter a value. [...]

But it has differing behavior between C and C++, when it comes to sign conversion:

> Warnings about conversions between signed and unsigned integers are disabled by default in C++ unless `-Wsign-conversion` is explicitly enabled.

What is the reason of this? Do C and C++ differ in some way regarding signed/unsigned conversion, which makes it more dangerous in C? Or is there any other reason for this?

Comment: @rsp: That's not a proper explanation. There's a lot in common. "Do C and C++ differ in same way regarding signed/unsigned conversion, which makes it more dangerous in C?"

Comment: I don't think it is anything to do with language differences,  just an arbitrary decision by gcc developers

Comment: C++ and C have difference rule about sequences points. You should ping gcc dev.

Comment: @Stargateur: Why do you think sequence points are relevant? That seems a very strange connection to make.

Comment: @MSalters Just a idea, but if sequence point are different maybe sometime conversion is more "safe" in C++

Comment: @Stargateur: I don't see the connection between conversions and sequence points either. Can you explain what do you mean?